# Migrate PrestaShop 1.5.x to a new server and a new domain

Tags: hosting, prestashop, web-hosting, prestashop-1.5

I am very new to prestashop , I modified a prestashop theme whch was hosted in my server with a sub domain. Now I want to migrate the entire site to a new server with a new domain. These are the steps I followed:

1> I didn't install prestashop in the new server

2> copied all files from my server to the new server domain folder

3> backed up the DB using PHP Myadmin and restored the same in new server

4> changed the DB connection strings in settings.inc.php

Now , when I am trying to access the new domain it is taking some local IP something of this sort

```
http://192.168.1.110.../box/index.php?
```

What did I miss ? Do do I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the back-office go to Preferences -> SEO & ULRs and modify Shop domain, SSL domain and optionally Base URI.

Alternatively you should modify `domain`, `domain_ssl` and optionally `physical_uri` fields in the `ps_shop_url` table.